# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL Failing on DO server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, digital-ocean

I have developed a Django app that uses GCP and tested the code on the dev environment, I am using a JSON service account key file and working fine on the dev environment. But failing in the staging env (DO server with nginx and gunicorn). Getting the following error: 
"Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started"
I tried with export env variable and also setting explicitly, But no luck. Any idea what's the reason/solution to this. The dev and stage env using the same source code and working on the dev and failing on the staging env. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code in which you are setting the credentials? It's hard to know what went wrong without seeing this information.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without a description of how you deploy gunicorn, but you can configure `gunicorn` to set environment variables.  E.g. with [Systemd](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#systemd) you can set it like this:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
# stuff omitted
Environment=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/foo/bar/my-creds.json
ExecStart=/path/to/bin/gunicorn \
      --workers 4 \
      --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
      sa.wsgi:application
```